# Программа сортирующая точки координат в разные массивы

Tags: java

```
public class SortPoints {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = args[0]; // first p 
    String[] firstSplit = string1.split(";");
    String[][] secondSplit = new String[firstSplit.length][2];
      for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
        secondSplit[i] = firstSplit[i].split(",");
        }
     int[][] first = new int[0][0];
     int[][] second = new int[0][0];
     int[][] mainArray = new int[firstSplit.length][2];
     for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
       mainArray[i][0] = Integer.parseInt(secondSplit[i][0]);
       mainArray[i][1] = Integer.parseInt(secondSplit[i][1]);
            }
     String string2 = args[1]; // second p
     String[] splitString2 = string2.split(",");
     String string3 = args[2]; // third p
     String[] splitString3 = string3.split(",");
     int x1 = Integer.parseInt(splitString2[0]); // x of first point
     int y1 = Integer.parseInt(splitString2[1]); // y of first point
     int x2 = Integer.parseInt(splitString3[0]); // x of second point
     int y2 = Integer.parseInt(splitString3[1]); // y of second point
     for (int i = 0; i < firstSplit.length; i++) {
     if (distance(mainArray[i][0], mainArray[i][1], x1, y1) <= distance(mainArray[i][0], mainArray[i][1], x2, y2)) {
       first = addToMassive(first, mainArray[i][0], mainArray[i][1]);
         }
         else {
           second = addToMassive(second, mainArray[i][0], mainArray[i][1]); 
           }
     }
     sort(first);
     sort(second);
     for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++)
     System.out.print(first[i][0] + "," + first[i][1] + " ");
     System.out.println("");
     for (int i = 0; i < second.length; i++)
     System.out.print(second[i][0] + "," + second[i][1] + " ");
     }
     public static double distance(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
     double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - y1), 2) + Math.pow((x2 - y2), 2));
       return dist;
     }
     public static int[][] addToMassive(int[][] array, int x, int y ) {
     int[][] newFirst =  new int[array.length + 1][2];
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     newFirst[i][0] = array[i][0];
     newFirst[i][1] = array[i][1];
     }
     newFirst[newFirst.length - 1][0] = x;
     newFirst[newFirst.length - 1][1] = y;
     return newFirst;
     }
     public static void sort(int[][] a) {
       for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
         insert(a, i);
     }
     } 
     private static void insert(int[][] a, int index) {
       for (int i = index; i > 0 && a[i - 1][0] > a[i][0]; i--) {
         int tmp = a[i - 1][0];
           a[i - 1][0] = a[i][0];
           a[i][0] = tmp;
     }
   }   
}
```

Нужно написать программу, которая принимает 3 параметра через командную строку.
Первый параметр: это лист состоящий из каких-то точек на пример 81,71;89,43;-92,64;-28,-34;-2,60;-11,58;97,-84;-37,19;-56,-51;-35,-60
( у каждой точки есть x и y координаты на пример x = 81 y = 71)
Второй и третий параметры: это какие-то точки на пример 30,73 и 22,-22

Программа должна рассчитывать расстояние между каждой из точек листа то есть 81,71;89,43;-92,64 .... и
точками 30,73 и 22,-22 и рассортировывать в два массива точки из листа в зависимости от того к какой из двух точек 
ближе точки из листа, а потом рассортировать точки в массивах от по x координате от меньшей к большей, если у двух точек x координаты равны то по y координате.
Пример того, что должна выдавать программа при заданном листе и двух точках:
-92,64 -11,58 -2,60 81,71 89,43
-56,-51 -37,19 -35,-60 -28,-34 97,-84

Я написал программу так, но в конце не могу рассортировать точки в массивах.
А мне выдает:

```
-92,71 -11,43 -2,64 81,60 89,58 

-56,-34 -37,-84 -35,19 -28,-51 97,-60
```

Answer (score 1):

В духе странного написания вам нужно добавить в метод insert

```
int tmp1 = a[i - 1][1];
a[i - 1][1] = a[i][1];
a[i][1] = tmp1;
```

Вы меняете x [0], но забыли поменять y [1].